# Nameerror: name 'h' is not defined

Tags: python, if-statement, input, nameerror

So I am trying to write a small script in python that will differentiate inputs, and when the appropriate input is given, an `int`, it will give the correlating answer. I know there are a number of posts on this topic that are similar but I was having trouble finding my answer. Here is what I have.

```
oktas = input("Oktas: ")

def sky_condition(oktas):
   if isinstance(oktas, int) == True:
      if oktas == 0:
         print ("CLR")
      elif oktas == 1 or oktas == 2:
         print ("FEW")
      elif oktas == 3 or oktas == 4:
         print ("SCT")
      elif oktas >= 5 and oktas <= 7:
         print ("BKN")
      elif oktas == 8:
         print ("OVC")
      elif oktas < 0 or oktas > 8:
         raise ValueError("Oktas provided are above or below the allowed limits.")
   elif isinstance(oktas, int) == False:
      raise NameError("You suck at following instructions.")

skycondition(oktas)
```

When you put in an `int` or a `str`(as in something in "quotation marks") then it processes everything as it should. However if I just put a letter or word without quotation marks, for example h, it raises the error

```
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

It produces the error I want but not how I wanted it. How can I code it so it will raise the error how I want it?

Comment: Is this Python 2? If so, you should consider using `raw_input` instead of `input`, and then attempting to convert to an integer using `int(oktas)`. (also, please add the `python-2.x` tag, because this is one area where the behaviour is different to Python 3)

Comment: `isinstance` already returns a Boolean value; there is no need to check if it equals another Boolean value to generate a *third* Boolean value.

Comment: See the nuances of `input` (which apears to be your problem) in this other [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15129556/5847976)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things wrong with your code, I will try to point them out, fix them and explain to you what you are doing wrong.

```
oktas = input("Oktas: ") #returns str only if you are running Python 3.x+. 
                         #returns int if it's an int for Python 2.x
                         #not sure which version of python you are running. 

def sky_condition(oktas):
   if isinstance(oktas, int) == True:
      if oktas == 0:
         print ("CLR")
      elif oktas == 1 or oktas == 2:
         print ("FEW")
      elif oktas == 3 or oktas == 4:
         print ("SCT")
      elif oktas >= 5 and oktas <= 7:
         print ("BKN")
      elif oktas == 8:
         print ("OVC")
      elif oktas < 0 or oktas > 8:
         raise ValueError("Oktas provided are above or below the allowed limits.")
   elif isinstance(oktas, int) == False:
      raise NameError("You suck at following instructions.")

sky_condition(oktas) # you had skycondition(oktas) which wasn't your function name.
```

Overall this program works, just typos on your end. If you are running Python 3, you will have to do some error checking for the input `oktas` since like I said, Python 3.x returns a str for `input()`. You will need to cast the input with `int(oktas)` but then that would basically defeat the purpose of your `isinstance()` check since it will be an int. A good way of working around this is:

```
if oktas.isdigit():
     oktas = int(oktas)
     #rest of your code
```

The `isdigit()` function returns true if a str contains digits 0-9 only, then you can cast your `oktas` to int.

Like the comment says if you are using Python 2.x you should avoid using `input()` and use `raw_input()`. A few reasons:

`raw_input()` basically it will return a `str` object no matter what you give. If you give it `5` it will give you a str object: `"5"`
If you give it `"5"` it will give you a str object: `"5"`

`input()` this is where your problem is. In Python 2.x input is basically doing `eval(input())`. You can read up on [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) here. Basically it tries to evaluate the given expression. Since numbers and strings are expressions themselves, it will try to run your `h` input as literally `h` instead of a str. Once again use `raw_input()` to avoid this in Python 2.x.

I'm assuming you are using Python 2.x or you have other codes you aren't showing. Use `raw_input()` and cast your input accordingly.

Comment: This still doesn't address specifically why inputs such as `h` do not work, but `"h"` does. You should explain why that doesn't work to help the OP understand more (perhaps mention that Python 2's `input` uses `eval`?)

Comment: Fair enough I will edited it.